# How to get top 10 Keys in decreasing order of their values for the Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java

```
map.put("Tom",5);
map.put("Tim",2);
map.put("Ted",4);
```

And then I could broadcast it like:

```
Tom is 5
Ted is 4
Tim is 2
```

How may I do this? I'm beginner in coding, please don't punish me so hard.

Comment: Take a look at the `TreeMap` class.

Comment: @Marcelo That won't help here.

Comment: You are right @arshajii, that only orders the map by key.

Comment: stackoverflow not here to solve your home work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
List<Entry<String, Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Entry<?, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<?, Integer> a, Entry<?, Integer> b) {
        return b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue());  // reverse order
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Entry<String, Integer> e = l.get(i);
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " is " + e.getValue());
}
```

---

**Reference:**

- [`Map.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)
- [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)
- [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and pass a `Comparator` in the constructor which keeps your entries in the desired order, then just iterate over your `entrySet`.